# python: how to generate char by adding int

Tags: python

I can use 'a'+1 to get 'b' in C language, so what the convient way to do this in Python?
I can  write it like:

```
chr(ord('a')+1)
```

but I don't know whether it is the best way.

Comment: It'll work. What do you mean by 'best'?

Comment: Be warned that strings in Python are stored with an encoding. In Python 2.x, the default encoding is ASCII to which adding an integer should not be a problem. In Python 3.x, strings by default are UTF8 unicode. You'll get an error when adding an integer to unicode characters if it overflows beyond 127. http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type

Comment: @shimofuri, python 3 strings are Unicode. Utf-8 is an encoding.

Comment: And **why** do you want, given 'a', to get 'b'? What's the larger problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, this is the best way. Python doesn't automatically convert between a character and an int the way C and C++ do.

Comment: It's not a conversion, but different semantics (integer, character) for the same stored bit pattern.

Comment: Still, there is the "bytearray" type - quite convenient when ne do need to manipulate characters by their value.

Answer (score 9):

Python doesn't actually have a character type, unlike C, so yea, chr(ord is the way to do it.

If you wanted to do it a bit more cleanly, you could do something like:

```
def add(c, x):
  return chr(ord(c)+x)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is the `bytearray` type in Python - 
it is slower than regular strings, but behaves mostly like a C string:
it is mutable, acessing  inidividual elements raise 0 - 255 integer numbers, insetead of substrings with lenght 1, and you can assign to the elements. Still, it is represented as a string, and in Python 2, can be used in most places a string can without being cast to a str object:

```
>>> text = bytearray("a")
>>> text
bytearray(b'a')
>>> print text
a
>>> text[0]+=1
>>> print text
b
>>> text[0]
98
>>> print "other_text" + text
other_textb
```

When using Python 3, to use the contents of a bytearray as a text object, simply call its decode method with an appropriate encoding such as "latin1" or utf-8":

```
>>> print ("other_text" + text.decode("latin1"))
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is really the right way. Python does not conflate a character with its numerical codepoint, as C and similar languages do. The reason is that once you go beyond ASCII, the same integral value can represent different characters, depending on the encoding. C emphasizes direct access to the underlying hardware formats, but python emphasizes well-defined semantics.